# How to stop default href action

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom-events, href

I have code in the below format in my JSP.

```
<a href="javascript:submit()">sumbit</a>
```

On pressing the link my form gets submitted. However, I need to block the default a href behaviour and just need to call the submit function.The submit function submits the form

I have tried catching the click event on a HREF by jQuery and then firing `e.preventDefault()`. Following the same, I have picked up the HREF attribute, and then done an `eval()` to fire the function.

However, I have not been able to stop the default HREF functionality, and a new page is always saved in browser cache.

I also don't have the freedom to manually go in and change the code. Please suggest.

**UPDATE**

The issue with the code is:

```
<a href="javscript:submit()">submit</a>
```

is one of the example of HREF being used in JSP. There may be different type of functions being called, using the above format:

I had used the below jQuery:

```
$("a[href^=\'javascript\']").live('click',function(e)
{
     e.preventdefault();
     eval($(this).attr('href'));
     return false;
});
```

However, this does not stop the default HREF functionality. What am I missing?

Comment: Does `submit()` submit a form? Then yes, that's what it'll do. You need to use Ajax to submit the form in that case.

Comment: Can you please comment on your last line "I also dont have the freedom to manually go in and change the code" - if you can't change anything what kind of help you are looking for? Also consider showing your sample of "catching the click event on a href by jQuery" as it should be working ok.

Comment: Wait. You want to submit the form but prevent what default behavior?

Comment: "and a new page is always saved in browser cache." Show us your submit() function.

Comment: @minitech, the answer has been delete but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/qB6Bd/) is what I was trying to say

Comment: @Jashwant: Oh, okay. I got the message that it wouldn't work because it was a *function* in general...

Comment: I have updated my question. Could yoy please look..

Comment: When i said , i dont have the option of changing the code, means  i cant go ahead and make changes in individual jsp, as that would be looking for lot of edits. I needed a jqueery which would work in a generalized perspective

Comment: Did you mean to use the wrong capitalization? You need to use `.preventDefault` - notice the "D"

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question, you cannot manually change the markup.

So, I think, this is what you really want.

```
<form id='myform' action=''>
</form>
<a href="javascript:submit()">submit</a>​
​
```

**JS:**

```
 function submit() {
   document.getElementById('myform').submit();
 }


 jQuery(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
         var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('javascript:','');
         console.log(href); 
         alert('hi');
         eval(href);        
         return false;
     });
 });​
```

​

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/JdURa/)

**Update:**

You can avoid `eval(href)`, by using `window[href]();`

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/JdURa/1/)

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. I hope it's not because of the `eval`

Comment: Dear *downvoter*, do comment next time you downvote someone. Downvote without a reason doesnt help. If `eval` was the reason, I've updated my code.

Comment: Hi Jashwant, I acnt do this change, as this would require me to update the indiviudal files, which would really eb a lot. Is there a generic way, in which i can call any function folowwing "javascript:" and at the same time prevent the default href behaviour

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`<a href="#" onclick="submit()">sumbit</a>`